# how to update wsp / solution programmatically

Tags: solution-package

I am trying to find a way how to update a SharePoint solution programmatically with C#. (I already know how to do this with the powershell command Update-SPSolution).

I have tried using this code but it doesn't work:

```
SPSolution sol = SPFarm.Local.Solutions[name]; //name = mytest.wsp
sol.Upgrade(filePath); //C:\mytest.wsp
```

Can anyone provide some guidance?

Comment: How is it not working? What is your Farm topology? (Number of front ends etc.) If it is a multi front-end farm try to use the Upgrade overload with a DateTime parameter to schedule a TimerJob, this will execute on all Web servicers. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spsolution.upgrade.aspx

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work" you must get some kind of error, try using ULS Viewer to capture error if nothing comes up in event receiver

Comment: At the moment it is a Dev-Server with all components (MSSQL, Front-End) on one system.

Comment: "It doesn't work" means that nothing happens :-(

Answer (score 1):

You are using the correct code (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms455619.aspx).  When I do this, I usually specify DateTime.Now for the second parameter. This code schedules a deployment job the same way the Update-SPSolution Cmdlet does.

What I would suggest is to run this code and then immediately refresh the Farm Solutions page to see if there is a change in status. Additionally you could use this PowerShell to see if a deployment job exists:

Get-SPTimerJob | Where-Object { $_.Name -Match "solution-deploy" }

Additionally you can check the solution itself for an existing job:

(Get-SPSolution solution.wsp).JobExists